# NodeJS Heroku Deployment error

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am using heroku for my web app. Last few days, I made some changes and made few commits and push to github repos, but not to heroku.

Does this make any problem? Today I tried to push my app to heroku and it spits error message, but I hardly understand what is really a problem.

Here is the error message I got from heroku

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
   engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

   Resolving node version (latest stable) via semver.io...
   Downloading and installing node 5.11.1...
   Using default npm version: 3.8.6
-----> Restoring cache
   Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
   - node_modules (exists - skipping)
   - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
   Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
   Rebuilding any native modules

   > fsevents@1.0.15 install /tmp/build_beaf0bc7e95fb8f9c62b3c6e646e1f10/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
   > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

   module.js:341
   throw err;
   ^

   Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_beaf0bc7e95fb8f9c62b3c6e646e1f10/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js:15:11)
   at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:367:17)

   npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-100-generic
   npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_beaf0bc7e95fb8f9c62b3c6e646e1f10/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_beaf0bc7e95fb8f9c62b3c6e646e1f10/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
   npm ERR! node v5.11.1
   npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! fsevents@1.0.15 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the fsevents@1.0.15 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fsevents package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
   npm ERR!     npm bugs fsevents
   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls fsevents
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/build_beaf0bc7e95fb8f9c62b3c6e646e1f10/npm-debug.log
-----> Build failed

   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

   Some possible problems:

   - node_modules checked into source control
   https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits

   - Node version not specified in package.json
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

   - A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies

   - This module may be specified in 'devDependencies' instead of 'dependencies'
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#devdependencies

   Love,
   Heroku
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution.

Literally, the error message was created because of the lack of fsevents. And I figured out fsevents is the module only that can be installed and run in Mac OS. While my laptop and the heroku server aren't not Mac.

The problem was just created because we are working on the project using github with my coworker. I use ubuntu and he uses Mac. He tried to install ionic in his laptop, and the fsevents came with ionic installation.

After all, I uninstalled ionic, and I could successfully deploy my project to heroku.

The link below helped me to figure out it. Please refer to it if you wanna check it.
https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/411